# SSRS report does not show up in my application but works perfectly fine at server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reporting

I am trying to display reports in my application (.NET MVC 4 framework) and I have a test report displaying perfectly. This report has 1 parameter which is passed by the application and displays in the reports page as shown below:

[image]

The table below the header 'ProgramInformation' also displays perfectly. Now the real reports I need to display have 2 parameters as shown below:

[image]

When I choose the 'Program Year' value (e.g. 2013), and click 'View Report', The page refreshes and the value of 'Program year' returns to 'Select a Value' and the page remains blank as seen above. When I run the same report directly on the Reports server, it works perfectly! 
I have looked everywhere and found solutions stating that it could be a browser issue -- that it works in IE and the fix to make it work in Chrome is to change the CSS style from 'overflow:auto' to 'overflow:visible'. This is definitely not that issue since the report does not show irrespective of the browsers.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED:** It was a PostBack issue. In the webform (.aspx.cs file) I had to pass the parameter value only if PostBack was false on Page_Load i.e.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
     //Pass Parameters or do whatever.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... Had been biting my nails for 2 days